# jquery - Timer?

Tags: jquery

I need to call my function `abc()`, 5 seconds after the `document ready` fires.

Is this possible in jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//Wait 5 seconds then call abc();

});

function abc() {}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//Wait 5 seconds then call abc();
    setTimeout(abc, 5000);

});
```

[`setTimeout()`<sup>link</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Answer (score 8):

Use `setTimeout("abc();", 5000);` in your ready function.

**Example (Don't use this, see below)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //Wait 5 seconds then call abc();
  setTimeout("abc();", 5000);
});

function abc() {}
```

The 5000 tells it to wait 5000 milliseconds which is 5 seconds. This is a basic JavaScript function and doesn't require jQuery (other than of course, the ready state event code). You can also use `setInterval()` if you want something to happen a recurring amount of times.

**Edit**: You can read more about it here(link removed).
**Edit3**: While my answer was not incorrect, it was not the best way to do it (as brought to my attention by david in the comment below.) A better way of doing it would be to pass the function `abc` itself directly into the `setTimeout` function. Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //Wait 5 seconds then call abc();
  setTimeout(abc, 5000);
});

function abc() {}
```

This is better form because you're *not* passing the string argument which is `eval`'d and could cause [security risks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval!).

Also, a better link for documentation is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout).

Comment: Don't use w3schools as a resource. It teaches you bad practices, like using `setTimeout(string, number)` instead of `setTimeout(function, number)`. See: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @david: Fair enough. That's a valid point. **Edit:** I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    setTimeout(abc, 5000);

});

function abc() {}
```

Comment: Just for the record, all three of us posted our responses within seconds of each other. This question was fairly low hanging fruit.